# add a commandline command to a file rename batch

Tags: java, windows

I have a working file rename java tool, now I want to add an if condition to run a commandline command if I checked a box as part of the rename process on each file it renames.

I will be changing the dos code later, but its a sample I found that works. Part of my problem is my filerename is its own class, so I will also need to figure out how to combine this class or reference the dos command somehow from my main rename class.

**update**

I updated the code with the changes from the answer, but the commandline command does not work and it crashes java with no error. The command does work from cmd line.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class doscommandrun {
     public static void run() {  
         final String dosCommand = "cmd converter.exe file.doc -android -o file.txt";
            try {
                final Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
                        dosCommand + " ");
                final InputStream in = process.getInputStream();
                int ch;
                    while((ch = in.read()) != -1) {
                        System.out.print((char)ch);
                    }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

`enter code here`File rename code:

```
private void renameFile(){

    boolean operationResult = false;
    boolean overallResult = true;
    int failCount = 0;

    /* the operation of this part is ensured by the chooseDirectory()
     * WE get the list of files in the directory
     * get the conditions set by users
     * and perform the file rename operation.
     */

    //Let's get all the information from user
    String[] fileList = directory.list();  //the list of files in the directory
    String Prefix = txtPrefix.getText();
    String Rename = txtRename.getText();
    String Suffix = txtSuffix.getText();
    String digits = (String) cboSequence.getSelectedItem();
    int StartingNum;
    String generatedSequence;
    File oldFile;

    //let's call the output frame
    if(cbxOutput.isSelected() && OUTPUT_ON == false){
        buildOutput();
        OUTPUT_ON = true;
    }




    //display the list of files and readability of each file
    for(int i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++){   
        oldFile = new File(directory.getPath()+"/"+ fileList[i]);
        String readability = fileList[i] +" - readable?: "+oldFile.canRead();
        System.out.println(readability);

        if(OUTPUT_ON)
            txaOutput.append("\n"+readability);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++){

        /* get the file extension that we need, and form a new name, 
         * we would check if the Ignore File Extension is selected
         */
        oldFile = new File(directory.getPath()+"/"+ fileList[i]);

        String fileExtension;

        if(cbxIgnoreExtension.isSelected() == true ){
            fileExtension = "";
        }
        else
            fileExtension = getFileExtension(fileList[i]);

        //this part get the original filename       
        String fileName = getFileName(fileList[i]);



        String inputInfo = "The input filename->"+ fileList[i] + "\nfile name->" + fileName + "\nextension->" + fileExtension;   
        System.out.println(inputInfo);

        if(OUTPUT_ON)
            txaOutput.append("\n"+inputInfo);



        /* generate sequence for the Name
         *if the digits selection is NONE, we ignore it
         */
        if(digits.equals("None") == true){
            generatedSequence = "";
        }
        else{
            StartingNum = Integer.parseInt(txtSequence.getText());
            generatedSequence = nameSequence(StartingNum + i, digits);
        }




        //this is affected by the RenameOption, if Rename has something then only we RENAME
        if(cbxRename.isSelected() == true){
            fileName = Rename + generatedSequence;   //the fileName will change.
        }
        else{
            //if Rename has nothing, but the txtSequence has some Value, we take it to the naming too
            fileName = fileName.substring(0,4)+ generatedSequence;
            if(cbxAndroid.isSelected() == true ){
                doscommandrun.run();
                }



        //the New File Name
        String newFileName = Prefix + fileName.substring(0,4) + Suffix + fileExtension;
        String tentativeName = "new Filename will be ->"+newFileName+"\n";
        System.out.println(tentativeName);

        if(OUTPUT_ON)
            txaOutput.append("\n"+tentativeName);




        // ! Perform the file rename, if the Experimental Mode is not selected
        if(cbxExperiment.isSelected() == false){

            operationResult = oldFile.renameTo(new File(directory.getPath()+"/"+newFileName));
            String renameResult = "\t*Rename successfully?: " + operationResult+"\n\n";
            System.out.println(renameResult);
                if(operationResult == false)
                    failCount++;

                if(OUTPUT_ON)
                    txaOutput.append("\n"+renameResult);

            //make up the overall result
            overallResult = (operationResult && overallResult);
        }

    }

    if(cbxExperiment.isSelected() == false){
        System.out.println("Overall Result: "+overallResult);
        if(overallResult)
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "All files renamed successfully!");
        else
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File renamed with "+ failCount+ " failure(s)");
    }//end if
    }

}//end renameFile
```

Comment: please make your question more specific. It's difficult to understand exactly what you're asking

Comment: @jerhynsoen You have to read data both from input and error streams of your process.  Otherwise, you will run into problem when error occurs. For this you will have to use Threads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add /c after the cmd in my renametool class

I am still having issues but wither a different problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a static method in the doccommandrun class called `run()` which will execute what is currently in the main method when called.

```
public class DosCommandRun 
{
   public static void run() 
   {
      //..do stuff from main
   }
}
```

Now whenever you want to call the dos command you can just insert `DosCommandRun.run()` into your code.

Comment: I udpated my code to do what you suggested but that did not work. I update the code in this quetion to reflect those changes.